# Apache 404 Error While PHP File Exists

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, chmod

I am getting 404 error while the file exist.  I gave the file (chmod 755) still the file does not show up.  Strange part it only happens to few files.  I am certain the file exists on the directory and PHP file have no script errors.  My .htaccess file says

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://mydomain.com/404.shtml
```

This only happens on my Google Chrome browser and it works fine on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

If it only happens in some browsers but not in others, have you tried clearing the browser cache? ErrorDocument with an absolute URL will send a redirect, which might be cached in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your servers log files? Can you check if your browser actually made a request, and if your server sent out a 404 error? This should be the first thing to check, to decide if it was a server-side error, or just a problem with the browser/proxy caching pages, and serving a cached 404 error page.